# How to fix IE table, radio, and checkbox quirks when printing?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, printing, css-tables

I need to print a page in IE8, IE9, and Chrome. It prints perfectly in Chrome, no so well in IE8 (have not tested IE9 yet).

The 3 major problems I'm facing with IE right now are:

1. Checkbox and radio button width is messed up and it has a border
2. Extra padding throughout the form, especially between label and field
3. Internal table borders do not show up, and the first column should be hidden

See the screenshots below. Why is this happening? I can't seem to fix it, I've tried changing the css several times. I know it is reading the CSS though.

**Checkbox:** 
[image: Checkbox width is messed up and it has a border]

**Extra padding everywhere:**

[image: Extra padding throughout the form]

**No internal table borders:**
[image: Internal table borders do not show up + first column should be hidden]

**UPDATE:**

The form shows up correctly (table borders shown, padding correct, etc.) in both Chrome and IE. It prints correctly in Chrome. It does not print correctly in IE.

Please do not tell me to print the form another way. I've made a design decision to print it from the browser: it's what's best for my project.

Comment: When you need nice-looking printouts, generate them as a PDF on the server and let the user download and print it themselves. Printing has never been a priority in browser development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a simple table with borders to the page to test if IE not displaying table borders, or if my css was some how overridden. When that worked, I realized my table was being selected somewhere else by it's ID (and having it's borders removed). When I tried to add in the borders for printing, I was selecting the table by it's class name not ID.

I also realized the jquery.jqprint plugin was not including the doctype in the iframe it was printing. Now, it prints perfectly in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

1: You probably have something like

```
input {border: ...; width: ...}
```

which affects your checkboxes and radios. At least in Internet Explorer. You can fix this either by using

```
input[type=radio], input[type=checkbox] {alternating styles}
```

or by assigning specific classes:

```
input.radio, input.checkbox {alternating styles}
```

2: The padding you might get rid of by giving both the input-forms and the label right next to it

```
text-align: vertical
```

3: To solve the borders you should provide the CSS for that ;)

Comment: I have separate styles for the radio and checkboxes already. I've tried setting the width to 13px (size it is on the form) and the border to none. Perhaps I wasn't clear about the padding, there should be less space between label and input. It's not an alignment issue for me.

Comment: mmh, yeah, well, you should make a jsFiddle then :) Something to see live.